# Minizinc: how can I make the union of a set in this situation (fix point algorithm?)

Tags: arrays, set, union, minizinc, fixed-point-iteration

I have an array of sets that means that the items inside the set must finish before the actual one starts. For example:

```
before = [ {},
      {1},
      {},
      {},
      {2}];
```

I'm looking to make each line include the ones who go before recursively. So in this case, it should end up like this:

```
abans = [ {},
      {1},
      {},
      {},
      {1,2}];
```

I've tried generating a variable and creating the sets from blank, but I didn't manage to do it. Any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

**CASE 1:** `before` is a variable.

Let's take the following list of tasks:

```
enum TASKS = { A, B, C, D, E };
```

We declare an array `before` to hold the set of blocking tasks for each task:

```
array [TASKS] of var set of TASKS: before;
```

A task should never block on itself:

```
constraint forall(i in index_set(before))
    (
        not (i in before[i])
    );
```

A task `i` inherits the block-set of each task `j` blocking task `i`:

```
constraint forall(taskset in before)
    (
        forall(task in taskset)
        (
            before[task] subset taskset
        )
    );
```

You can append:

```
 solve satisfy;
```

And find all possible solutions:

```
~$ minizinc test.mzn --all-solutions
before = array1d(TASKS, [{}, {A}, {A, B}, {A, B, C}, {A, B, C, D}]);
----------
before = array1d(TASKS, [{B}, {}, {A, B}, {A, B, C}, {A, B, C, D}]);
----------
before = array1d(TASKS, [{}, {}, {A, B}, {A, B, C}, {A, B, C, D}]);
----------
before = array1d(TASKS, [{}, {A, C}, {A}, {A, B, C}, {A, B, C, D}]);
----------
before = array1d(TASKS, [{}, {A}, {A}, {A, B, C}, {A, B, C, D}]);
----------
before = array1d(TASKS, [{}, {}, {A}, {A, B, C}, {A, B, C, D}]);
----------
before = array1d(TASKS, [{B, C}, {}, {B}, {A, B, C}, {A, B, C, D}]);
----------
before = array1d(TASKS, [{B}, {}, {B}, {A, B, C}, {A, B, C, D}]);
----------
before = array1d(TASKS, [{}, {}, {B}, {A, B, C}, {A, B, C, D}]);
----------
before = array1d(TASKS, [{C}, {A, C}, {}, {A, B, C}, {A, B, C, D}]);
----------
before = array1d(TASKS, [{}, {A, C}, {}, {A, B, C}, {A, B, C, D}]);
----------
before = array1d(TASKS, [{}, {A}, {}, {A, B, C}, {A, B, C, D}]);
...
```

---

**CASE 2:** `before` is an input parameter.

A task `i` belongs to `abans[j]` if it is contained in `before[j]`, or there exists a task `k` in `abans[j]` such that `i` is in `before[j]`.

Encoding:

```
enum TASKS = { A, B, C, D, E };

array [TASKS] of set of TASKS: before = 
    [{C}, {A}, {D}, {}, {B}];

array [TASKS] of var set of TASKS: abans;

constraint forall(i, j in TASKS)
    (
        i in abans[j] <->
        (
            i in before[j]
            \/
            exists(k in abans[j])
            (
                i in before[k]
            )
        )
        % circular dependencies are not allowed!
        /\ not(j in abans[j])
    );

solve satisfy;
```

Output:

```
~$ minizinc test.mzn --all-solutions
abans = array1d(TASKS, [{C, D}, {A, C, D}, {D}, {}, {A, B, C, D}]);
----------
==========
```

Comment: It's actually an input, sorry for not specifying it. Would it change much?

Comment: @Stasky not much, actually.. can you derive the correct constraints from this answer? Otherwise I'll edit the answer for you

Comment: I think that's not exactly what I was asking for. I'm given as input an array with n sets of ints inside. What I want to do is, for example, if the set in position array[5]={3}, then array[5] should contain the union of array[5] U array[3].

So: [{3},{},{2},{1}] would become [{3,2},{},{2},{1,2,3}]

Comment: @Stasky that's exactly what happens with the `before` array in my own answer. Since you find it confusing i'll edit the answer. Give me some minutes.

Comment: okay, thank you very much. I've been trying to mess with your current answer but I get "WARNING: model inconsistency detected"

Comment: @Stasky Edited. Notice that the provided solution assumes that there is no circular dependency. (That should probably be a forbidden input).

Comment: That works great! Thank you very much! I'm still learning this and was of great help!